# Is "on-parade" an actual term?

Tags: expressions

A google search came up with almost nothing.  Am I just imaging things?  I could have sworn one could use the term "on-parade" to mean a succession of something.
For example:

Life is an on-parade of unexpected events.

or something like that.

Comment: I've never come across hyphenated **on-parade** at all, let alone as a *noun* usage. Are you sure you're not getting confused with *"Life is an **ongoing parade** of unexpected events."*?

Comment: Hm.  Yes, that could be it.

Comment: Is it possible you misheard [nonpareil](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonpareil) which kinda sounds like 'on parade'.

Answer (score 2):

One meaning of the term is clearly military. 'Parade' is a formal ceremony at the start of the day/shift etc, where formalities, inspections, roll-calls etc take place. Soldiers, and other armed forces personnel, taking part are said to be 'on parade'. Being 'late on parade', or otherwise deficient in being prepared, kit not in proper order etc., is a disciplinary offence for which privileges can be lost.

Comment: WS2, considering that soldiers are not the only category of armed forces personnel who have parades, your answer could be improved by replacing the word *soldiers* with *military personnel*.

Comment: @Tristanr Yes, point taken. But *military personnel* sounds a bit American to me. I have a sense we might say *armed forces personnel* or something. Whichever way, 'late on parade' is not a smart thing to be.

Comment: WS2, that's a good point. *Armed forces personnel* is probably more appropriate. You could put that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common(ish) phrase, though not hyphenated. If memory serves, it relates to a feeling of being on display. Alternately, a ceremony with much pageantry.  Examples:

- "On our trip to the Capitol, we spend all morning on parade."
- "The fourth was predictably full of unbridled patriotism on parade, in this case literally."
- "The investors' meeting consisted of engineers on parade."

Try using the define search term:

```
define "on parade"
```

I get [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=on%20parade#q=define%20%22on%20parade%22&safe=off), though that is not especially informative.  Oh god, the more I look at the google results, the less it feels like a real phrase.

The search term

```
"* on parade"
```

[results in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%2a%20on%20parade%22) a billion things that get paraded about. Bulls, Christmas, pies, pianos, pets, Wall Street, mermaids.